# How to print text between css selectors in golang using html package?

Tags: html, css, go

I have html document

```
<value>1,2,3</value>
 <value>,1,3,5</value>
```

and what to extract text with code below but it only prints 'value' tags (css selectors). How to print the text from between tags instead using golang html package ?

```
z := html.NewTokenizer(b)
    for {
        tt := z.Next()
        switch {
        case tt == html.ErrorToken:
            return
        case tt == html.StartTagToken:
            t := z.Token()
            isAnchor := t.Data == "value"
            if isAnchor {
                fmt.Println(t.Data)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the `Text()` method that you're looking for ? 
https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Tokenizer.Text

Comment: Yeah, not sure how to use it here. t.Text ?

Comment: I think StartTagToken's Data will always contain the tag's name (in this case "value"). You should advance the tokenizer once more to get the TextToken. It's Data should be the text itself (i.e "1,2,3").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
r := strings.NewReader("<value>1,2,3</value><value>,1,3,5</value>")
doc, err := html.Parse(r)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
var f func(*html.Node)
f = func(n *html.Node) {
    if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "value" {
        fmt.Println(n.FirstChild.Data)
    }
    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
        f(c)
    }
}
f(doc)
```

I think the key is grabbing the FirstChild after finding the "value" node.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Text()` method on the next `Token`.

```
if isAnchor := t.Data == "value"; isAnchor {
    z.Next()
    fmt.Println(z.Text())
}
```

Comment: z.Next().Text undefined (type html.TokenType has no field or method Text)

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: now: z.Next().Token undefined (type html.TokenType has no field or method Token)

Comment: Edited again. Hope I don't have to do it again ;)

Comment: for some reason it prints me empty brackets [] as Text. I think I had it before. I tried to change to <value>1</value> with single character but makes no difference

Comment: Try replacing `Text()` with `Token().Data()`